# Nome não fica fixo na variável

Tags: angular

Bom dia! Tenho uma pesquisa que coloco os nomes de alguns produtos em uma variável, porem, se eu pesquisar outro produto, ele subscreve o novo produto no antigo, dessa forma:

**Pesquisa de 1 produto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pesquisa do 2° produto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver, ele substitui o valor do segundo do primeiro, e até entendo o motivo, mas não sei como resolver... 
Obs: é só o nome do produto.

**Código de Pesquisa do produto:**

```
 case 'nomeProduto':
   params = params.set('cod', formGroup.controls['codigoProduto'].value);
   this.retornaNomeApi(NEGOCIUS_API + '/Pesquisa/RetornaNome', params).subscribe(nome => formGroup.patchValue({ nomeProduto: nome.result }));
   break;
```

**Página ts:**

```
  Codigo: any;
  digitacaoForm: FormGroup;
  itens: ItemPedidoModel[] = [];
  nomeProd: Produto[] = [];
    ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.type = params['type'];
      });
    this.digitacaoForm = this.fb.group({
      pedido: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      codigoCliente: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      nomeCliente: this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: true }),
      rep: this.fb.control('Selecione...', Validators.required),
      tipoped: this.fb.control('Selecione...', Validators.required),
      prazo: this.fb.control('Selecione...', Validators.required),
      forma: this.fb.control('Selecione...', Validators.required),
      codigoProduto: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      nomeProduto: this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      Quantidade: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      precoTabela: this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      PrecoDigitado: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
      precoTotal: this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
    });
  }

  retornaApi(url: string) {
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }

  GerarCodigo() {
    this.retornaApi(API + '/Pedido/GerarCodigoPedido').subscribe(codigo => (this.Codigo = codigo))
  }

  pegaNome(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    this.nomeProd = Object.assign('', formGroup.controls['nomeProduto'].value);
    return this.nomeProd;
  }

  excluirLinha(codigo: any) {
    for (let item of this.itens) {
      if (item.codigoProduto == codigo) {
        this.itens.splice(this.itens.indexOf(item), 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

**HTML da tabela:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div *ngIf="itens.length" class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th class="text-center">Código</th>
          <th class="text-center">Descrição</th>
          <th class="text-center">Quantidade</th>
          <th class="text-center">Preço Digitado</th>
          <th class="text-center">Preço Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of itens">
          <th class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="excluirLinha(item.codigoProduto)">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </button>
          </th>
          <td class="text-center">{{item.codigoProduto}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{nomeProd}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{item.Quantidade}}x</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{item.PrecoDigitado | currency: 'BRL': true}}</td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem como postar o código inteiro e do html tbm?

Comment: @EduardoVargas Adicionei o código da tabela, precisaria de mais algum código?

Comment: Posta o ts inteiro por exemplo vc esta fazendo o for neste itens e não tem ele no ts.

Comment: @EduardoVargas na realidade, o itens não vai ter muito haver com o que eu estou tentando resolver, eles vão apenas ser passados por parâmetro, sem nenhuma ligação com o nome do produto, onde está o problema

Answer (score 1):

Tenta copiar o valor do string ao invés de passar a referencia

```
 this.nomeProd = Object.assign('', formGroup.controls['nomeProduto'].value);
```

Comment: eu tentei, dessa forma, porem o nome do produto não aparece mais na tabela, teria que fazer mais alguma coisa fora isso?

Comment: dificil saber ja que vc esta assignando uma string a um valor que espera um array  nomeProd: Produto[] = [];
  pegaNome(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  return formGroup.controls['nomeProduto'].value;//seria melhor assim 
  }

Comment: Se eu trocar o para string, daria certo apenas chamar?

Comment: Nao sei eu preciso ver o resto do codigo

Comment: Coloquei todo o código ts

Comment: Precisaria colocar o model?

Comment: poderia ver o código e me dar alguma resposta?

Comment: não sei, não vi como vc chama o pegaNome ou seta o items, tenta reproduzir num stackblitz

Comment: Eu pensei assim, o model que recebe o valor do item é o ItemPedidoModel, e nesse model possui um campo chamado "nomeProduto", teria como eu botar o resultado dessa minha pesquisa pra esse campo?

Comment: mas se vc tem um campo pesquisa e vários items todos sempre vão ter o mesmo nomeProduto pois nessa sua logica so tem um nomeProduto.

Comment: voce tem que usar o push para ter um array de nomeProd. Ai com o index do seu for vc consegue acessar ele.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79490/discussion-between-bruno-miqueas-and-eduardo-vargas).